# Exact statement of a theorem.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

So I have two versions of a theorem that I have wrote down in my notes from lecture.

Ver 1: If $B$ is a finitely generated algebra over a Noetherian ring $R$ and it is also a finitely generated module over a Noetherian ring $R$ and $B$ is also a finitely generated module over a submodule $A$ then $A$ is a finitely generated algebra over $R.$

Ver 2: If $B$ is a finitely generated algebra over a Noetherian ring $R$ and $B$ is also a finitely generated module over a subalgebra $A$ then $A$ is a finitely generated algebra over $R.$

Which one is the correct version?

Comment: The second one is correct: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%E2%80%93Tate_lemma

Comment: The first one is hardly understood (at least for me).

Comment: Much thanks!!!!

Comment: @user26857: could you make that an answer so the question doesn't hang around forever in an unanswered state, please?